# Installed Virtualenv and activating virtualenv doesn't work

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I cloned my Django Project from Github Account and activated the virtualenv using famous command `source nameofenv/bin/activate`
And when I run `python manage.py runserver`

It gives me an error saying:

> ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Comment: *Are* you sure it's installed? How did you install it?

Comment: I just activated virtualenv and tried to use python manage.py runserver command, I think after activating virtualenv there is no need to install any dependencies or is it ? I don't know much!

Comment: But you still need Django from somewhere! How are you expecting it to be in your virtualenv if you don't install it?

Comment: I was thinking that every and each dependency I need, might be present inside virtualenv. If that is not the case then I was wrong! This means I have to install all related dependencies of that project?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I was thinking that every and each dependency I need, might be present inside virtualenv.

Well, no. By default, a newly created virtualenv comes empty, that is, with no third-party library. (Optionaly, you may allow a virtualenv to access libraries installed system-wide, but that's another story.)

Once the virtualenv is created, you need to install the dependencies you need.

(How could virtualenv know what dependencies you need?)

The procedure is to install the virtualenv, activate it, and then install the libraries needed for the project (in you case Django and perhaps others).

If you project has a requirements.txt, you may install every required dependency with the command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

If your project has a setup.py, you may also execute

```
pip install -e path/to/your/project/clone/.
```

to install the project in the virtualenv. This should install the dependencies.

Of course, if the only dependency is Django, you can just type

```
pip install django
```

Comment: Do you mean installing django into the venv folder that is "C:\Users\John Uzoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\venv" ?

Comment: Well, activate the newly created venv, and from there, execute `pip install django`. Don't copy folders manually.

Answer (score 14):

on ubuntu version

```
#install python pip 
sudo apt-get install python-pip
#install python virtualenv
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
# create virtual env 
virtualenv  myenv
#activate the virtualenv
. myenv/bin/activate
#install django inside virtualenv
pip install django
#create a new django project
django-admin.py startproject mysite
#enter to the folder of the new django project
cd mysite
#run the django project
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Sorry bro, I forgot to mention that I am working on MacOS. thanks for answering :)

Comment: ok when activating your virtualenv  if you run pip freeze command it must return smth like django== your django version 

try to install django in your virtualenv via command pip install django

Comment: @abhi_bond Is there a file named `requirements.txt` in the top directory of your project?

Comment: @ Dimitris I doesn't have django installed when I used pip freeze command, This seems that I have to install Django. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: No Alain, I didn't create requirements.txt file while uploading that project from my another PC. Anyways Thanks :)

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis, I think your answer was downvoted because you gave command lines with no explanation.

Comment: `--no-site-packages` is a DEPRECATED option for virtualenv. Also I think he is not dealing with installing pip in their MacOS.

Answer (score 5):

If you have several `python` on your machine, for example,`python2.7`, `python3.4`, `python3.6`, it is import to figure out which version the `python` really reference to, and more over, which version does `pip` reference to.

The same problem got in my way after I installed the `let's encrypt` when I run the following command.

```
(python3 manage.py runserver 0:8000 &)
```

I inspected the `python` version and found that `python3`, `python3.4`, `python3.6`, `python3.4m` were all available.

I just change `python3` to `python3.6` and solved the problem.

```
(python3.6 manage.py runserver 0:8000 &)
```

So, this is probably a version mismatching problem if it is OK for a long time and  crashes down suddenly.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you also upload the virtual environment from your other pc. And you hope that only activating that will work, bzz.

It's not recommended to upload the virtualenv files to your git repository, as @Alain says it's a good practice to have a `requirements.txt` file containing the project dependencies. You can use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` (when the environment is activated) to generate the project requirements file.

By doing so, when you clone the repository from another computer, you need to create a new virtualenv by issuing the command:

```
virtualenv nameofenv
```

then activate it:

```
source nameofenv/bin/activate
```

and finally, use the requirements file to install the requirements for your project using:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I had installed Django 2 via `pip3 install Django`, but I was running `python manage.py runserver` instead of `python3 manage.py runserver`. Django 2 only works with python 3+.