# Django ImportError from django.core.management

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have tried everything to make it work

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "leke.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Please Help That's the error I have been getting from the manager.py . Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39934906/installed-virtualenv-and-activating-virtualenv-doesnt-work this might help

Answer (score 0):

Django might not able to install the package.
i'm not sure this is a solution but did the trick for me.

```
sudo pip install django --upgrade
```

and if you get an error of pakage *psycopg2* than install this first with

```
sudo pip install psycopg2 --upgrade
```

tell me if this works.

also try to use this on pytohn3+

if still doesn't work  [try](https://django-configurations.readthedocs.io/en/0.1/) django-configurations¶

Comment: If you're using this on virtualenv then plz make new virtualenv with latest Django and django-configurations¶

this will work i think

Comment: what's virtualenv?

Comment: virtualenv is a virtual environment for Ubuntu which helps to create a separate space for your projects and you can install apps in virtualenv.

Comment: I'm using windows 10

Comment: I'm not familiar with the windows environment. sorry bud.